# Validate domain name (without url scheme) with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to validate domain name (without url scheme) with jQuery. The user must enter a valid domain name in textbox. Here are the valid entries:

```
abc.com
def.net
ab-de.com
```

Invalid entries:

```
a bc.com
http://testdomain.com
https://testdomain.com
```

Comment: There are TLDs that are MUCH longer than 4 characters, such as example.photography.  There are also countries that have second level domain names reserved, and the user's domain starts at the third level: example.co.uk.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this ([Example][1]):

```js
function isValidDomain(domain) {
  var pattern = /^[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,6}$/i;
  return pattern.test(domain);
}

console.log(isValidDomain('abc.com'));
console.log(isValidDomain('abc.net'));
console.log(isValidDomain('abc-def.com'));
console.log(isValidDomain('abc-def.com.bd'));
console.log(isValidDomain('www.abc-def.com'));
```

Comment: You might want to add tests that fail validation just for completeness :). Also there's more extensions than .com and .net.

Comment: Agreed @StackOverflowed :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
function is_valid_url(url)
{
    return url.match(/^[a-z0-9-\.]+\.[a-z]{2,4}/);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this for just 'domainname.extension':

```
    var pattern = /^[a-z0-9-\.]+\.[a-z]{2,4}/;
    var domainVal = $('#domain').val();
    if(pattern.test(domainVal)) {
        alert('correct');
    }
    else {
        alert('no');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var pattern = /^(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?([a-z-]{2,}\.)?[a-z\-]{3,}[\.]{1}([a-z]{2,4})(\.[a-z]{2,4})?$/;
```